# What would be a use case for dynamic_cast of siblings?

Tags: c++, inheritance, siblings, dynamic-cast

I'm reading Scott Meyers' More Effective C++ now. Edifying! Item 2 mentions that dynamic_cast can be used not only for downcasts but also for sibling casts. Could please anyone provide a (reasonably) non-contrived example of its usage for siblings? This silly test prints 0 as it should, but I can't imagine any application for such conversions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B {
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
};

class D1 : public B {};

class D2 : public B {};

int main() {
    B* pb = new D1;
    D2* pd2 = dynamic_cast<D2*>(pb);
    cout << pd2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Search `cross-cast`. It is used when a class inherits from two different classes, not the other way around (as in your question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scenario you suggested doesn't match [sidecast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast#Explanation) exactly, which is usually used for the casting between pointers/references of two classes, and the pointers/references are referring to an object of class which both derives from the two classes. Here's an example for it:

```
struct Readable {
    virtual void read() = 0;
};
struct Writable {
    virtual void write() = 0;
};

struct MyClass : Readable, Writable {
    void read() { std::cout << "read"; }
    void write() { std::cout << "write"; }
};
int main()
{
    MyClass m;
    Readable* pr = &m;

    // sidecast to Writable* through Readable*, which points to an object of MyClass in fact
    Writable* pw = dynamic_cast<Writable*>(pr); 
    if (pw) {
        pw->write(); // safe to call
    }
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/CPOF78868)

Answer (score 3):

It is called *cross-cast*, and it is used when a class inherits from two different classes (not the other way around, as shown in your question).

For example, given the following class-hierarchy:

```
A   B
 \ /
  C
```

If you have an `A` pointer to a `C` object, then you can get a `B` pointer to that `C` object:

```
A* ap = new C;
B* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(ap);
```